# Customize getting data from SugarCRM Custom Module by Query parameter in rest api

Tags: api, rest, sugarcrm

Hi I'm trying to get data from SugarCRM by REST api. It's fine with default module, but with custom module, I got a issue.

I used this [example](http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/03_Developers/100Web_Services/100REST_API/100Examples/100PHP/Retrieving_a_list_of_records_-_REST_and_PHP)

And getting data from Contacts module which has last name = "abc" is ok with these code:

```
$get_entry_list_parameters = array(
     'session' => $session_id,
     'module_name' => 'Contacts',
     'query' => "contacts.last_name='abc'",
     'order_by' => "",
     'offset' => '0',
     'select_fields' => array(
          'id'
     ),
     'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(
     ),
     'max_results' => '1',
     'deleted' => '0',
     'Favorites' => false,
);
```

When I tried to get data from our custom module (eg: Event Session inside Event package), so it's ok as well without Query param like these code

```
$get_entry_list_parameters = array(
     'session' => $session_id,
     'module_name' => 'event_event_session',
     'order_by' => "",
     'offset' => '0',
     'select_fields' => array(
          'id',
          'name'
     ),
     'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(
     ),
     'max_results' => '3',
     'deleted' => '0',
     'Favorites' => false,
);
```

But after that I put Query param, I got no record

```
$get_entry_list_parameters = array(
     'session' => $session_id,
     'module_name' => 'event_event_session',
     'query' => "event_event_session.name='def'",
     'order_by' => "",
     'offset' => '0',
     'select_fields' => array(
          'id',
          'name'
     ),
     'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(
     ),
     'max_results' => '3',
     'deleted' => '0',
     'Favorites' => false,
);
```

I think the way I used to get data from custom module is not correct.
Anyone can help me resolve this issue. Thank you!

Johnny

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the table name for the custom module is "event_event_session"?

Comment: Yes, of course. Its name is Event Session in Event package, so the custom module name is event_event_session. Do you have any idea for our issue.

Answer (score 1):

When we create any new custom module using module builder then it is asking for key name. So our module will become as key_modulename. So make sure you are passing the key name along with module name. So that way you can access the data of custom new module.